# Reload just one tab in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

How can we reload one tab , means one request of many in QLikview.

PS:
I have one request per tab

Help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about 1 tab in the front end of QlikView you cannot refresh it as the entire model is driven by the underlying data and data structure.

You can set up partial reloads that will reload only certain tables of in that data.

Answer (score 0):

One request per tab is not ideal, recommended practice is that separate data is held in separate Qlikview documents.

However, this can be achieved - using variables and locally stored QVD's and the script below. You can also control variable values on the UI using buttons and actions on objects. The QVD's hold the data and are only reloaded when expressly requested.

```
            //choose which data to load 1 = load query from scratch
            Let vLoadQuery1=1;
            Let vLoadQuery2=0;
            Let vLoadQuery3=0;
            Let vLoadQuery4=0;
            Let vLoadQuery5=0;

            if vLoadQuery1=1 then 
            //Enter load details and capture in local QVD
                //Load
                Query1:
                LOAD *;
                SQL select * from some.data;

                //Store
                STORE * from Query1 into Query1.qvd (qvd);
                Drop Table Query1;
            ENDIF
            //Load from QVD - if this hasn't been loaded on this reload, it will grab the previous data
            NewQuery1:
            LOAD * 
            FROM Query1.qvd (qvd);
```